# Cuisinart frozen yogurt recipes confusing

Tags: ice-cream, frozen-yogurt

I just bought an ice cream maker (ICE 70) and it came with an instruction/recipe book, but the recipes for the frozen yogurt are confusing.

One example is like this

- 2 cups whole milk, plain Greek yoghurt
- 1/4 cup granulated sugar
- 4 cups frozen mango pieces
- 1 teaspoon lime juice

So on the first ingredient they say two different things, whole milk and yoghurt, but am I supposed to use both, or only one of these?

For example am i supposed to use

2 cups whole milk AND 2 cups yoghurt?

OR

2 cups combined whole milk and yoghurt (1 cup each)

OR

2 cups only of whole milk  OR 2 cups only of yoghurt (I choose which one)

Does anyone know?

The recipe says:

[image]

Comment: A recipe wouldn't be a recipe if it wasn't confusing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I read that as 2 cups of Greek yogurt made from whole milk (ie not low- or non-fat yogurt).  The comma does make it confusing, however.

Comment: Thinking about it, you end up with ice-cream if you just use the milk. :)

Comment: And that adds up (2 cups yogurt, 4 cups mango, makes 6 cups) so you know it's not some horribly unclear way of saying "2 cups of *each*".

Comment: It would be fixed with an extra comma. Whole milk, plain, Greek yogurt.

Comment: Or not using any commas. "Whole milk plain Greek yogurt" would be the natural way to say it.

Comment: Or write it as "Plain whole milk Greek [style] yogurt" (this seems to be the way it is listed on, for example, the [WholeFoods website](https://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/product/chobani-plain-whole-milk-greek-style-yogurt-32-oz-b004b3kmtq)).